# Marque starts again after ajax modifies dom elements

Tags: html, css, ajax

```
<table>
    <tbody id="output">
    </tbody>
</table>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
    refreshDiv();
});

function refreshDiv()
{
    dataString = 'x=fetchData';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajaxpage.php",
        data:dataString,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
            $('#output').html(result.tabledata);
        },
        complete: function() {
            setTimeout(refreshDiv, 5000);
        }
    });
}
```

ajaxpage.php

```
$str = '';
$data = fetchFromDatabase();
foreach ($data as $dd)
{
    $str .= '<tr><td>column1</td><td>column2</td><td><marquee>Marquee with some long text</marquee></td><tr>';
}
echo json_encode(array('tabledata' => $str));
exit();
```

I am populating above table body using ajax in every 5 seconds.
One of the row column contains a marquee. Since table body is updating in every 5 seconds, marquee starts over again.

Is there any way to retain marquee position in this case.

Comment: Its difficult to visualize what you are describing, so please edit your question and attach a fully functional self verifiable minimal snippet of your code, so that we tell you what's wrong.

Comment: `<marquee>` is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.

Comment: @Code_Ninja I have edited my question

Comment: @FedeSc Ok I will use my own css to move the text. But how to retain the last position after ajax populates the table

Comment: @JohnWick Are you replacing the same rows each time?

Comment: @FedeSc Yes, i am replacing it each time

Comment: @JohnWick you don't really have an out of the box solution with Marquee. it doesn't save coordinates thus you can't really pass them to an event or function. but it is expected that when you attach a domelement with javascript it will 'reset' the marquee. that's js behaviour